# click a button inside onActivityResult() after capturing an image from camera in android app

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Button Click
        }
    }
}
```

Here if the RESULT_OK,how to click a button and do whatever we want. Please Help me to find the solution.I have used  `if(getTaskId()==R.id.PassImageBtn){}` but nothing is happening if I click on the Button.

Comment: Is it necessary to look for button click. You can create a function to do what you are doing in that button click.

Comment: Actually I want to crop the image based on the user Input. i.e Passport size and Stamp Size.So I want a button click there.Since I want fixed size crop, I have implemented this link code in my app:https://github.com/oginotihiro/cropview I dont want user to resize height and width while cropping.So I have used this.

Comment: Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getApplicationContext(), photo);
       
            File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));
            int x = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            int y = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            // cropView.of(source).withAspect(x,y).initialize(MainActivity.this);
            cropView.of(Uri.fromFile(finalFile)).withAspect(x, y).initialize(StudentDetails.this);

Comment: This is my code.If user choose Passport Image then I want to perform this.

Comment: clickListener of button won't execute on its own in callback methods, you can write clickListener event in onCreate(), it will execute. Put checks or flag to handle the logic you want to write under the action of that button wrt result you are getting in onActivityResult()

Comment: @ A.R Ok.Can you tell an example code to do this?Since I wanted that captured image path too,I thought getting the button id inside onActivityResult and I can do the cropping.

Comment: Anyone can tell the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use **performClick**() method to the call button click event.

```
private Button mButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    mButton = findViewById(R.id.my_button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // ...
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mButton.performClick();
        }
    }
}
```